# SAS EG image in footnote

Tags: sas, footnotes, enterprise-guide

i would like to insert an image in the footnote. What command should i use ?
For example , my image file is locate at "C:\Image\img_footnote.jpg".

thanks.

sreenshot image link(not enough reputation to post an image here) :

http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/684/sasegreportfootnote.png/

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're using ODS HTML...

`footnote "<div><img src='c:\image\img_footnote.jpg'></div>";`

Comment: i just doing it on SAS EG report format...i have add screenshot for it.